# Export data using DataPump (SQL/PLUS, Oracle)

Tags: oracle, oracle12c, datapump

I need to copy whole schema("ABC") from one host to another one. I'm doing like this:

```
expdp user/pass@host dumpfile=test1.dmp logfile=test1.log schemas=ABC
```

Then I will import this file to my other host.

Can you please tell me, if it will copy everything? like package, procedures, triggers etc...?

Or I need to add something more?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it will *copy* everything.

No, you don't need anything else.

Comment: You could have done it simply by testing it. Create user, export, import, compare. If something's wrong, drop user (you'll need the *cascade* option) and repeat the action. There's nothing you can do wrong, as long as you don't put that "new" user into production. Additionally, by performing export/import several times, using different options, will make you self-confident. Win-win situation, so - go ahead.